# Public KML file not found using "maps.google.com/maps?q=" or JS API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

**Edit**

Solved... Compressed file and uploaded as kmz file. to same path. Now shows correctly in http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://sailingofftheedge.com/kml/testfile.kmz

----------Original Question--------------

Trying to set up a simple embedded map using API v3 and while the map itself displays fine, Google does not seem to be able to read the publicly available KML file needed for the overlay.
sailingofftheedge.com/kml/testfile.kml (File size 290.4KB)

https://maps.google.com/?q=http://sailingofftheedge.com/kml/testfile.kml Returns file not found.
feedvalidator.org/ returns a few warnings about validation, but is able to access and parse the file.

Suggestions?

Comment: There is something wrong with your server.  If I load the file I downloaded from your server from my server, [it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/sailingofftheedge_testfile.kml), if I load it from your server, [it doesn't](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://sailingofftheedge.com/kml/testfile.kml) (I get "fetch error")

Comment: @geocodezip Odd... Server log files show all requests for file status 200 eg: [11/Oct/2014:06:40:39 -0400] "GET /kml/testfile.kml HTTP/1.1" 200 297366 sailingofftheedge.com "-" "Kml-Google; (+http://code.google.com/apis/kml), gzip" "-"